# What is this strange light in photo?

Tags: raw

I found a picture from my camera archive 2012, which I need explanation about. It looks like either something happened to the camera or a certain light was captured.

[image: light]

Comment: "raw" would only be relevant if this artifact (probably perfectly ordinary lens flare)  was invisible or notably different in the jpeg or tiff file.

Comment: I redacted the email address for quick damage control. Not a good idea to post personal email addresses in cleartext here, you'll get drowned in spam.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysterious signs or easily explainable artifacts?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/99778/mysterious-signs-or-easily-explainable-artifacts)

Comment: Visiting Angel left a feather behind?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a [caustic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_(optics)), a shape that is produced by refraction of bright light at curved surfaces, most prominently when curved in more than one axis. Glasses filled with a clear liquid frequently show such effects, but even an empty drinking glass or bowl can do so.

To me it does not look like a lens flare at all. Most importantly you can see the shape conform to the recesses in the wall or ceiling.

Addendum: It might be produced by reflection from a strongly curved surface as well.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare) from the lens. This happen when the light source is close to the angle of view of your lens.

> Lens flare refers to a phenomenon wherein light is scattered or flared
>   in a lens system, often in response to a bright light, producing a
>   sometimes undesirable artifact within the image. This happens through
>   light scattered by the imaging mechanism itself, for example through
>   internal reflection and scattering from material imperfections in the
>   lens. Lenses with large numbers of elements such as zooms tend to
>   exhibit greater lens flare, as they contain a relatively large number
>   of interfaces at which internal scattering may occur. These mechanisms
>   differ from the focused image generation mechanism, which depends on
>   rays from the refraction of light from the subject itself.
>
> Flare manifests itself in two ways: as visible artifacts, and as a
>   haze across the image. The haze makes the image look "washed out" by
>   reducing contrast and color saturation (adding light to dark image
>   regions, and adding white to saturated regions, reducing their
>   saturation). Visible artifacts, usually in the shape of the lens iris,
>   are formed when light follows a pathway through the lens that contains
>   one or more reflections from the lens surfaces.

From the observation of @xenoid it can be also caused by water drop on the front element of lens.

Comment: It could also be that the flare is being projected onto the wall from another source and that is why the photo was taken (capturing an interesting effect) - I don't see much of a reason to photograph the wall otherwise, but then again, I wasn't there...

Comment: Lines look a bit distorted, as if the light was some drop of water.

Comment: @xenoid, interesting, it can be also reflection from water drop on the front element of lens. Will add it in the answer :)