# Photo Competition 2021-03-01: Straight out of camera

Tags: photo-competition

#### Theme

This theme seeks your best **straight-out-of-camera JPEGs**: no adjustments, curves, tweaks, post-processing, cropping, or straightening is allowed. Think "Polaroid", "Instax", "Kodamatic", etc.

Be as creative as you can before pressing the shutter button: external filters, in-camera filters, in-camera HDR functionality, scene modes, or other creative settings are acceptable **if set/configured before the image is captured**.

This also means no processed raw images: shoot RAW+JPEG if you want, but only submit the JPEG produced from the camera.

Scans of film shots are welcome to submit too. Please use your best judgment as to what constitutes "creative darkroom techniques" or scan touchups. Follow the spirit of the rule as best as you can.

There's no way to enforce the SOC rule, this is all on the honor system. Let's have some fun and see what we can get, Polaroid-style. =)

**Edit:** Editing for downsizing or reducing JPEG quality **only to satisfy the 2MB upload limit** is perfectly acceptable. Sorry for not making that clear originally.

#### Voting Rules

- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on March 1, 2021 at 12:00 AM UTC**. The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Multiple entries are encouraged, but please don't spam answers. The aim is quality over quantity.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.**
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

- Suggest a theme for the next contest. Leave a single comment below in the format,

  > Theme: <*one sentence description*>
- Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next time.

Good luck!

Comment: I'd like to suggest "available darkness" as the next theme.  It's an old phrase from film photography days, when it was significant effort to get beyond ISO 1600 and still get an image with a full tonal scale.

Comment: I'm sorry to be nagging here, but this is not a question that fits within the SE modal of Questions and Answers. This is a META topic, and should belong on your META site. This now is featured in the HotNetworkQuestions, which I personally find very inappropriate.

Comment: @Luuklag, See (for one example): "[Proposal: Rules for *New* Photo Contest on Main Site](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5885/37074)", the decisions with respect to this have been made after a discussion on meta.

Comment: Are photos taken from a phone eligible too?

Comment: @AJ Better be since I posted two. I'm sure any camera is fine including a phone. Just don't do any processing aside from getting the picture to fit into the upload size restrictions.

Comment: @AJ absolutely, phone photos that aren’t edited are elgible.

Comment: Theme: Reflections. Use of mirrors or windows to get reflections.

Comment: Theme: Water. Photos must contain water (eg. bodies of water, ocean, water droplets, puddles, water sports, rain, underwater, flowing water, reflections off of water). Snow, ice, and steam count as well.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Maroon Bells in Moonlight** – *near Aspen, Colorado. September 25, 2015*

[image: Maroon Bells in Moonlight, near Aspen, Colorado, September 25, 2015. 2:45 AM]

Taken at the edge of Maroon Lake in the Maroon Bells Wilderness Area, west of Aspen, Colorado, USA, two nights before full moon at 2:40 AM.

Nikon D800E and PC-E Nikkor 24mm f/3.5 ED lens; ISO 3200, ƒ/5.6, 30 sec.

This was trying to dial in Scheimpflug tilt to maximize depth of field with a wide aperture, under dark conditions. I learned a lot in the effort; primarily, I still have a lot of practice to go.

Comment: how did you get those light spots? I'm new to photography so I don't know if they can be intentionally made

Comment: @sweetandtangy Which light spots, specifically? If you're talking about the tiny points of light, those are stars (yes, really). If you zoom in, you'll see they streak ever-so-slightly from upper-left towards lower-right, because the shutter was open for 30 seconds and the Earth rotated while the shutter was open. If you're talking about faint "smudges" of light near the upper-left and continuing towards the center, they are [lens flare](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9257/11924).

Comment: oh wow I did not expect them to be stars. I thought they were a type of light effect maybe coming from film processing (if your camera was a film camera). How did you manage to not overexposed everything else given how dim the stars probably were

Comment: @sweetandtangy Well, it was taken at 2:40 AM. Middle of night. The moon was 2 nights before full moon, so about 95% full. As it turns out, seemingly counterintuitively, a 95% moon is about half as bright (luminous intensity) as the full moon. A 100% full moon is about 18 stops (roughly 350,000 times) less light than the sun. I wasn't exposing for the stars, I was exposing for the scene, knowing it would look like daylight, using about 19 stops more exposure than a bright sunny day exposure would be.

Comment: It looks surreal and very peaceful. Congrats! If you're interested, the portion of the sky is a relatively empty region between Aquila & Capricornus. The brightest star is Altair, on the right (between two dimmer stars), and Deneb Algedi is on the left of the picture. Altair is a star of the [summer triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Triangle), so it makes sense it would be close to the horizon, late at night in September. Again, well done, this is the kind of picture I wouldn't mind hanging on my wall. I want to dip my toe into this lake after a long hike!

Comment: Wow, never thought one'd get a moonlit photo look as if it was sunlit. I was supposing that the stars are instead seeds of something like poplar or dandelion.

Comment: @Ruslan it’s hard to believe until you see it. But the moon is a very neutral reflector of the sun’s light, so the color temperature is the same. And since they both have very similar apparent sizes in the sky (about ½° across), and follow similar paths in the same direction, once the 18–19 stops of exposure difference is accounted for, the scene essentially looks the same, except for the stars of course.

Comment: @scottbb: Also, our eyes have a huge dynamic range. Without light pollution, and once eyes are accustomed to the darkness, it's impressive how well one can see in the mountains when the moon is full or almost full. You don't see colors as well as the D800E sensor, though. :D

Comment: By the stars and the Moon positions it looks more like September 26 2015, 0:40 MDT, see [screenshot from Stellarium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzWJs.png). The full Moon was on September 28 night in that year. I guess your 2:40 timestamp is your home-timezone time.

Comment: @Ruslan It was definitely Sept 25, I know because it was 3 evenings (starting from sunset 9/24) before the lunar eclipse (around 8pm MDT on 9/27). But after consulting TPE, I think you might be right about the time. I'm US east cost (UTC -4:00 for EDT), as opposed to UTC -6:00 for MDT where it was taken. I remember spending quite a bit of time adjusting focus and tilt without direct moonlight because the moon was behind Pyramid Peak (just to the SW of my location). But you're right, if it were 2:40 MDT, the moon would have been too far west (almost directly above N. Maroon Peak).

Answer (score 28):

My profile picture:  **Black & White Self - Caveman**. Not sure about the "photojournalist-style", but it's definitely *straight out of camera*.

It's a self portrait, taken in front of my house, in Stuttgart, on the 26th of September 2009.

Shot with D90 in RAW+JPG mode, and BW preset already applied. The only thing I changed after taking the picture was to choose "M" size in order to stay under the 2MB limit. (Here's a [large JPEG](https://download.ericduminil.com/DSC_1484.JPG) in original size and with EXIF preserved.)

[image: self-portrait]

Here are the notes I wrote when I posted this picture on Flickr 10 years ago:

> This is one of the easiest tricks on a longboard. You don't even need
> to know how to ollie!
>
> Just take your board in one hand, run, jump, place your board under
> your feet, land and ride away....
>
> The most difficult part was to trigger the camera at the right time
> with an unreliable ML L3 trigger. I don't know if my batteries are
> running low, but I had around 20% success rate.
>
> Are there any other options for self photography? Something wireless
> but with 99% reliability?
>
> strobist, kind of cross lighting :
>
> bare SB-600, 1/4, 24mm, front camera left, mounted on a gorilla pod
> SLR on the floor (this flash casts the main shadow)
>
> snooted SB-25, 1/8, 85mm, back camera right, mounted 20cm away from
> the wall, parallel to both the wall and the ground in order to prevent
> casting shadows in the frame.
>
> Both flashes triggered by Cactus V4
>
> Camera triggered by an unreliable ML-L3 remote control in my right
> hand.
>
> D90 + Tokina 11-16
>
> 16mm, f/7.1, 1/200s

I cropped it a bit for my profile picture and [flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/eric_duminil/3957683139/in/album-72157612280355862/) but the above picture is untouched.

Answer (score 25):

[image]
It's a simple onion peel on an old board high in the mountains.

Mykulychyn village, Ukraine.

8 November 2014

Answer (score 25):

[image]

Taken with my Galaxy S9 and no filters on June 12th 2020 in North Idaho USA

Comment: What is so ironic about this shot is that I've spent days (or months for the solar eclipse) planning a shot but then this sunset just happened and was changing so fast I didn't have time to get my camera out so I was forced to use my phone. I'm thankful I was able to capture just how beautiful/scary the sky was.

Comment: Isn't that the way it goes? I love the careful planning and research to capture shots like eclipses, rocket launches, alpenglow sunrises in a certain part of the year, etc. But sometimes serendipity and a convenient pocket camera or phone produce some of the most memorable shots. Part of the pain/joy dichotomy of photography, I guess? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Nice! It looks like it was shot on Velvia.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what body of water is that? I used to spend a lot of time in North Idaho (By Pend Oreille/Priest) so this picture is super nostalgic for me :)

Comment: This is the Pend Oreille river just a couple miles outside of the town of Priest River

Answer (score 24):

I was just getting into hobby photography and had access to the base hobby photo lab as I learned to process and print B&W film.

**Out my barracks window** - Darmstadt Germany, 1974

[image: Out my barracks window]

Minolta SRT-303, Vivitar 70-210mm (*I think*)

**Per request for more detail:**

This was an American Army base in Darmstadt Germany, "Cambrai-Fritsch-Kaserne". To the left out of picture is the main gate. I'm on the 3rd floor on one side of the road. This picture is across the road and is actually an on-post day care facility. I thought the juxtaposition of the kids, the sign, and the barbed wire was interesting.

Answer (score 19):

My girlfriend taking her Minolta SRT303b apart for inspection. I like how you can still see all the mechanical parts and their function.
Hamburg, Germany / 14.02.2021

[image: Minolta SRT303b - scaled submission]

[View full-size submission](https://flixma.de/118FAF97-2510-4EFB-8EF8-15A76BDC344D-653-0000019DA5215DFC.JPG)

Fuji X-T4 7Artisans 35mm f0.95 1/52s ISO 1250

Comment: I love this one! The narrow focus makes it kinda mysterious as to what the rest of the mechanism is doing or looks like.

Comment: Thank you so much! We had a deeper look into the inner workings of the tiny bowden cable. It looks fairly complicated, but once you get the hang of it, those are basically just two wires going from the bayonet lens mount (for reading aperture) and the iso/shutter speed dial to a contraption moving an "brightness target" up and down in the viewfinder (this camera has a small button cell for reading brightness). Pretty stunning technology!

Comment: Oh wow! That sounds fascinating!

Answer (score 17):

Waltrop, Germany, Bumble Bee approaching Goldenrod, 2020-06-13

Resaved from Gimp with lower JPEG quality in order to fit upload constraints.
[image: Bumble bee approaching goldenrod]

Answer (score 16):

**"Reflecting"** - *Lincoln Memorial, Washington, D.C. - September 13, 2020*

[image: Reflecting]

Canon Powershot SX610 HS -
ISO 80,
77.62mm,
f=6.9,
1/160s

Answer (score 16):

[image: Flying home for Christmas.]

**Flying home for Christmas.**

Nikon D3100, Helios 44-2 (58mm), 1/60s, f=2, ISO 3200.
Hand-sized figure in front of Christmas tree. December 2020.

Answer (score 15):

Richmond–San Rafael Bridge, California, 9 June 2017 (Galaxy Note 5)

[image: Richmond–San Rafael Bridge]

Comment: It looks interesting! Were you flying or is there a huge mountain nearby?

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, it's from a plane.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Varkala, Kerala, India]

An evening shot from Cliff side beach in [Varkala, Kerala, India](https://goo.gl/maps/yVrLA9zS3WyVVDMA9). Resized to reduce the file fize. No other edits. Taken on 10th Sept 2017.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Cloud outside backdoor Bisbee Arizona 1/31/2021]

Cloud outside backdoor Bisbee Arizona 1/31/2021

Comment: Great example of a lenticular cloud!

Answer (score 14):

I've tried to adhere to the spirit of this, even though I can't obey the letter - so this was from my original NEF, opened in Ps, no adjustments made, then saved as a smaller jpg. My 'proper version' of this is just a tighter crop, but this is the full uncropped original.

The photo is a 90 second manual exposure using a cheap variable ND at almost maximum, I ran in half-way through & sat still.

[image]

BTW, it's titled "**Do** Fear the Reaper" which is a little lost at this size, hence the usual crop. Play on words on the song title in the sheet music on the piano - the *'nt* is covered by the leaf, blu-tacked on.

Comment: “spirit”... I see what you did there.

Comment: @scottbb - I shall steadfastly pretend that was entirely intentional & not in the slightest that I didn't even realise until you mentioned it ;))

Answer (score 14):

[image: Idaho Sawtooth Mountains]

Idaho Sawtooth Mountains on Sept 13, 2016. Taken with an iPhone 6s auto exposure. Only processing is reducing jpeg quality to fit upload constraints.

Comment: I really like this photo. Excellent detail and colors! +150

Comment: @scottbb Thanks. I took more with my good camera but wanted a picture on the iPhone to text to the kids. Amazing scenery.

Answer (score 13):

London, Big Ben, January 16th 2013

[image]

I didn't know much about photography back then (and still don't) but luckily, subjects like these are willing to stand still for a while to experiment with exposure time and other settings. Of ~25 photos, this was the only one where you could read the time. The Moon is overexposed though, but I like it so much that is has been my desktop background for nine years now.

Canon EOS 1100D, EF-S 18-55 mm, 18mm, 1/50 s, f=3.5

Answer (score 11):

No specific title, my cat napping in the sun. I'm by no means a pro, but always enjoy capturing either nature, or parts of daily life, like here, one of the daily naps of one of my cats.

Settings : Canon EOS 100D, EF-S 18-55mm, Focal 38mm, f/6.3, Exposure 1/100s

[image: picture]

Comment: Cats win per default on the internet ;-)

Comment: Simply adorable!

Answer (score 10):

No idea which flower that is, I was trying to do a boring macro shot, but messed up the settings. Allen's gardens, Toronto. Sept 5, 2020

[image: flower]

Comment: Looks like a [dahlia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahlia) to me.

Answer (score 9):

Cherry (?) Blossoms, March 2019, San Francisco area

[image]

Taken with an LG G3, allegedly ƒ/2.4, 1/1724, 3.97mm, ISO50

Answer (score 9):

Taken 24 August 2014 near Lac Pavin, Saint-Flour, Auvergne, France, with an Olympus Stylus TG-870.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image: A stem with a pink flower and a leaf framed by a lens fog]

- Taken with a Nikon D5300 using the 18-55 kit lens on September 23, 2016.
- It was a damp, drizzly day, and I was out walking around the hillside in my college campus. My lens fogged up, but the centre remained clear, which allowed me take this.

Answer (score 8):

The moon.

- November 19th, 2020 at 4:55PM, Santa Fe New Mexico
- Nikon D7500
- Sigma 150-600mm f/5-6.3 DG OS HSM Sports
- 600mm, 1/320s, f/6.3
- Resized to 25% to fit upload requirements

And I thought I was shoot RAW that day.  LOL

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Firework, 1 January 2021. Nottingham, U.K.

Shot on iPhone 11.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tim. I edited your post to use Imgur's image display option by adding an `l` (lower-case "L") to the image filename (before file extension). Note that I didn't resize your upload at all. Clicking on the image link still points to the full-size image you uploaded. I did this because Stack Exchange sizes large images to fit the width of the post area, which makes portrait-oriented images very large. If you don't like my edit, you can revert it. =)

Comment: @scottbb that’s fine! Thanks for running the competition!

Comment: @scottbb What's wrong with displaying portrait orientation images at full width? I prefer it to these smaller version. When clicking through, the image is usually way too tall to fit on a (landscape) monitor.

Comment: @MichaelC When displayed at the Imgur `l` size, the portrait images tend to have the same area as the landscape images that take the full width of the post area. That's all. Just a visual similarity so portrait images don't heavily dominate. I'll happily stop making adjustments; I admit it's only a personal preference.

Comment: I guess it all depends on whether one is viewing on a (vertical) mobile device or a (horizontal) monitor...

Answer (score 8):

[image: Tree, spotlights and snowfall]

**Tree, spotlights and snowfall** at Gorky Park, Moscow on January 01, 2019.

Taken on a *Huawei P20 Pro*, auto settings (f/1.8, 1/50s, ISO 100).

P.S. Had to resize image to fit 2 Mb limit.

Answer (score 7):

I find it very hard to reconcile the "straight out of camera" condition with the 2MiB size limit of image uploads.

However, this B&W photograph (using a red flash gel) qualifies.

Kitchen, "The Visitor", 2020-07-09
[image: The Visitor]

Comment: _I find it very hard to reconcile the "straight out of camera" condition with the 2MiB size limit of image uploads._ Yeah. Perhaps I should have added "_modulo image resizing_..." =)

Comment: Well, I am a stickler for rules.  When I found that my on-disk JPEG copy wasn't right-side up (for my own purposes I had rather worked with the raw version), I dug out the old memory card and did the rotation in-camera.  Since this only affects the EXIF info rather than the image data, I figured this should be ok.

Comment: Hmm. That makes me wonder about the film shots. How does a film camera know it's in portrait mode? ;-)

Comment: BTW, I hope you don't mind, I used the Imgur size option to display a slightly smaller image here. The image link still goes to the full-size that you uploaded, but for display purposes, rather than filling the width of the post area, a scaled version is shown.

Comment: As long as it doesn't get me disqualified...

Comment: @scottbb I once had some friends laugh at my negatives because I was shooting 6x6 with a Holga, and I shot some scenes in landscape and some scenes in portrait mode .. lol

Comment: Ok this is really weird - I'm using the StackExchange app and when I scroll past this photo, it very very much looks like the person's dark cloak actually moves. And shadows on the hand change slightly ...anyone else??

Answer (score 7):

Taken December 13, 2020 in Cabot VT. Backyard hill overlooking Winooski River. Taken with Nikon Coolpix W300. I had to "Adjust Size" down on the Mac to get it to a postable size (originally 3.8 MB[image: )]

Answer (score 7):

Taken September 28, 2020 on  [image]Highway 15, Walden VT. Taken with Nikon Coolpix W300. I had to "Adjust Size" down on the Mac to get it to a postable size (originally 3.8 MB)

Answer (score 6):

Rare(-ish) vehicle at my local garage, frosted over and back lit by morning sun:[image]
Nothing fancy, just my trusty OnePlus 5.

Comment: If anyone is curious it's a Volvo L3314 aka Valp (Puppy)

Answer (score 6):

I love happy accidents. I feel my camera skills are fairly decent and I have taken some good photos but sometimes I mess up and the results surprise me. We were hiking in Yosemite National Park and I usually leave my camera on auto to be able to take a quick shot of wild life or other situations where there isn't time to adjust the settings for the "perfect" shot. But in this instance I had switched to manual to take a photo in a bright light situation and forgot to switch it back to auto before I put my camera away. Well we came across this rock climber getting ready to rappel down the face of the mountain and I didn't want to miss the shot so I started shooting before looking at the camera to see what the settings were. By the time I noticed it was still on manual he was already down the face and I assumed the shot was ruined. But...
Canon EOS T5i
ISO = 100
f5.6
Exposure 1/800
Focal length 255mm[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: [1]

This is one of the dogs I sat in Vancouver, after losing my own furry baby to greedy vets. Her name is Milka (like the chocolate :D) and she's the silliest girl alive.

This was taken with Nikon D750, 50mm f1/8, 1/320s, ISO3200.

Answer (score 5):

**Lone Transmission** - *Hertfordshire, UK - July 10, 2020*

[image: Lone Transmission]

The preview compression kinda ruins the detail; click through to the full res JPEG for better viewing.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Exit Stage Left, John Perry Barlow]

Exit Stage Left.

John Perry Barlow at Terrapin Station, the first reunion concert of The Other Ones/The Dead after Jerry's death. Weekend of August 3rd & 4th 2002, Alpine Valley, East Troy Wisconsin.

Straight scan of Silver Gelatin print

Comment: For a brief moment, based on the title, I thought you were referring to a [different band](http://nerdywithchildren.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/tumblr_mby4eyRQOT1rbttddo1_1280.jpg). Nevertheless, respect. RIP Jerry.

Comment: @scottbb Well that weekend was a rush ;)  RIP, Neil Ellwood Peart.

Answer (score 5):

**Coastal Cairn** – *Juan de Fuca Provincial Park, Vancouver Island, British Columbia. August 13, 2018*

[image]

Taken with iPhone 7 and built-in "noir" filter with automatic settings.

Answer (score 5):

**Concert at the remains of the Roman Agora (just below the Acropolis) in Athens, Greece.**

*Taken on a Huawei P20 Pro, auto settings (equivalent to 35mm film, f/1.8, S 1/100s, ISO 64, HDR on, AWB) - Summer '20.*

[image: Roman Agora in Athens, Greece - Summer 2020]

You can notice the audience trying to be isolated from one another due to the ongoing pandemic.

The image is a bit distorted due to the phone lens and the colours/contrast/cropping not great, but it was taken in the heat of the moment and I think it gets the feeling of the moment across.

Comment: Do you know who was playing?

Comment: I did notice at the time but I can't remember now. As you can see it wasn't a very small concert, but these are common in Greece in the summer months :).

Answer (score 5):

**Bang!** *- Manchester, UK - November 2020*

[image: photo of firework oajh]

(Resized for upload requirements - may have lost some quality also).

A firework exploding over my balcony on Guy Fawkes Night 2020; I got incredibly lucky with the timing and framing of the shot...less so with the focus...

Answer (score 5):

[image: Seattle]

Seattle July 8th 2019. iPhone Xs. Reduced JPEG quality to fit upload requirements

Answer (score 5):

**The Stair at Skellig Michael** – June 11, 2019

[image: The Stair at Skellig Michael]

This is a view from the monastery atop [Skellig Michael](https://worldheritageireland.ie/sceilg-mhichil), an island off the coast of Ireland, once a retreat for ascetics and more recently a filming location for the Star Wars franchise. A weather warning caused an early return, and I was able to get this shot while the last visitors had climbed but before everyone started back down.

Sony a7R II, Lensbaby Composer II/Edge 35. ISO 100, 1/250, most likely f/3.5. Scaled with ImageMagick.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Flowers after a rainstorm

I took this photo in May 2013, after a rainstorm, while sitting on the balcony of the flat I shared with two fellow students. We had this single one plant on our balcony, and if it hadn't been for the occasional rain shower it probably would have withered by week three.

It was taken with a Canon EOS 1000D, 1/400 Sec. f/6,3 200 mm, 100 ISO.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

> **Margate, Kent, England**
>
> Canon PowerShot SX60 HS
>
> 28th May 2017

At the time I took the photo I didn't notice the couple holding hands by the beach.

Answer (score 4):

Zeiss-Ikon Super Ikonta B (532/16), ca. 1948, uncoated f/2.9 Tessar.

Arista .EDU Ultra 400 (= Fomapan 400), exposure unrecorded but probably f/16 at 1/250, processed in replenished Xtol stock.  Scanned, resized.

[image: Cat Tracks and Snow Diamonds]

Answer (score 4):

The currently largest container ship in the world, the HMM ALGECIRAS of the Korean shipping company Hyundai Merchant Marine during it's first visit to Hamburg in June 2020

[image]

original jpeg, resized to be uploadable on stack.imgur.com
ILCA-77M2, Tamron 1:2.8 70-200mm, 1/2 Sek. f/8 150 mm

Answer (score 4):

[image: Skyline outside Osaka castle]

Just the skyline outside Osaka castle on 2019/3/31.

Shot with ZTE Axon 7 A2017G. ISO 100, 1/432, F1.8

Man I miss traveling there...

Answer (score 4):

[image]

My cat, Zoe, 2012-02-12.

One of the first pictures I took with a new SEL 30mm/3,5 Macro lens on my Sonly A6000.

Answer (score 3):

**Sushi at a charity fundraising event**

Potomac, MD

February 2018

[image]

Taken on a Nikon D5100, using the original kit lens and the built-in flash with a flash diffuser cut from a cheap translucent white three-ring binder.

Answer (score 3):

**Heidi Fahrenbach at Three Musketeers Workshop**

Taken on 22 January 2019 at a workshop with [Guido Karp](https://guidokarp.com). The goal was indeed to show how close you can get to a final image with good lighting and settings. So while I took the image, I can only take limited creative credit for it, as the scene was pretty much given. I still like it as a reminder what is possible in cam.

Lighting was clamshell lighting with a softbox above and below.

Camera: Sony a7 III with Sony Macro 90mm 2.8

Settings: 1/160sec at ISO 200 and f4.0

If you wonder why ISO 200 although it is a strobe shot: The Bokeh balls are cheap fairy lights from a dollar-store held very close to the lens. On ISO 100 they already would have been too faint.

It is probably the image I have done the least in post ever. The edited raw only has minor skin retouch and some stray hair removed. Nowadays I no longer take a jpg alongside with the raw. And I lean heavily towards post production and composition.

[image: Heidi Fahrenbach]

Comment: Hi Kai. I edit your post to use Imgur's [image display option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189635/175991) by adding an `l` (lower-case "L") to the image filename before extension. Note that I didn't resize your upload at all. Clicking on the image link still points to the full-size image you uploaded. I did this because Stack Exchange sizes large images to fit the width of the post area, which makes portrait-oriented images very large. If you don't like my edit, you can revert it. =)

Comment: @scottbb Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Dresden]

[River Elbe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbe) as seen from the bridge [Albertbrücke](https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=51.0561&mlon=13.7557#map=16/51.0561/13.7557) in Dresden, Germany

2020-09-23

Samsung Galaxy S9

Answer (score 3):

Taken December 11, 2020 in Cabot VT. Butternut squash cubed for freezing. Taken with Nikon Coolpix W300. I had to "Adjust Size" down on the Mac to get it to a postable size (originally 4[image] MB)

Answer (score 3):

This is a fox from Yellowstone, taken out of a car on June 15th, 2019 with a Canon EOS T1i. ISO:1600, 1/640, f/5.6. Lens is a Tamron 70-300mm F/4-5.6 Di LD Macro. Image had to be downsized to fit within file size limits.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Taken April 29, 2019 in Cabot VT. "Mama?"[image]. Taken with Canon Powershot A2300. I had to "Adjust Size" down on the Mac to get it to a postable size (originally 2.1 MB)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Just for fun. This picture was taken with a somewhat unconventional camera,

> produced by Hewlett-Packard: a HP ScanJet G4050.

Answer (score 2):

Reclamation, 2003

Kawee Camera ("Patent Etui"), 13.5 cm f/4.5 Schneider-Kreuznach Radionar, 9x12 cm Fomapan 100, HC-110 Dilution E.  Exposure unrecorded.  Scanned, sized.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Last autumn, 11 Okt. 2020, @Timmendorfer Strand, Ostsee (Baltic See)
[image]

Sony ILCA 77MK2, Sony 1:2,8 16-50mm, 1/640 Sek. f/3,2 26 mm

Answer (score 2):

Traction Engine "Nightmare" taken at the Isle of Wight steam festival in August 2014. Taken on 120 B&W film with a 1934(?) Zeiss Ikon Super Ikonta A.

[image: Traction engine]

Answer (score 1):

Taken October 23, 2020 in Cabot VT.  Small tree, now named "Hamlet" framing moon.  Taken with Nikon Coolpix W300.   I had to "Adjust Size" down on the Mac to get it to a postable size (originally 3.8 MB)[image: Small tree, now named "Hamlet", framing moon]

Comment: Alas, poor Yorrick!

Answer (score 1):

**Rain**. Gasteig München, November 3, 2019

Self-portrait. Shot on a Pixel 3 XL from inside the building through a glass wall / window overlooking a street in the rain. Re-exported with reduced quality to fit 2 MiB.

[image: self-portrait in front of glass wall]

Answer (score 1):

Taken August 27, 2020 in Cabot VT. Pikeman. Taken with Nikon Coolpix W300. I had to "Adjust Size" down on the Mac to get it to a postable size (originally 4.0[image] MB)